# 404 page not found issue on all pages after upgrading Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

I updated Magento version  1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2 (CE) using following steps:

===== Steps to upgrade ======

After taking backup of all files and databases(.sql file).

1. Disable cache.
2. rm -rf lib/Mage/
3. rm -rf lib/Magento/
4. rm -rf lib/Zend/
5. rm -rf lib/Cm/
6. rm -rf lib/3Dsecure/
7. rm -rf lib/PEAR/
8. rm -rf app/code/community/Cm
9. rm -rf app/code/community/Phoenix
10. rm -rf app/code/core
11. Extract/install latest magento 1.9.2
12. Flush cache (rm -rf var/cache/*)

After updating magento, using above steps, I stuck into an issue of "404 page not found" on all pages

Comment: parveen pal,please put  your solution part at Answer section

Answer (score 2):

**Solved**

After struggling for many hours I found a issue which was on my magento store mysql tables. There was some incorrect entries when compared with latest magento version tables.

There is 3 tables ( core_website, core_store, core_store_group ) in magento which is responsible for magento stores. Compare all entries of these 3 tables with fresh install of magento mysql tables.

[image: core_store]

[image: core_website]

[image: core_store_group]

This solved my issue.

Hope someone find it useful.

Let me know if anyone having issue.