# Getting 404 - Page Not Found after upgrading to 1.9.3.7

Tags: upgrade, 404, 404-page, magento-1.9.3.3, not-found

I have to upgrade Magento from 1.9.3.3 to 1.9.3.7 and in that case I cloned the live system to an sub-domain of the live Domain. I always fixed the multi conflict with issue and getting upgraded I thought, but I dont know if it realy worked. Because when I hit the refresh Button after upgraden via Magento connect Manager I got an blank page and when I try to went back to the backend I got an 404 Error and also at the frontend. Every Site is gone into the Magento 404 Page.

I spend hours of time to fix it and try the solves of this threads:

- http://www.codesolutions.de/magento-404-error-auf-unterseiten-z-b-nach-serverumzug-loesung/
- [404 page not found issue on all pages after upgrading Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113665/404-page-not-found-issue-on-all-pages-after-upgrading-magento-ver-1-7-0-2-to-1)

But nothing works for me.

Do anybody knows a fix that I dont try until yet?

Comment: Did nobody knows a fix for that issue? I do realy need help with that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary Solution:

Goto **'core_cache_option'** table and set all the values to **0**

(You are disabling all the **Cache Types**)
block_html, collections, config, config_api, config_api2, eav, layout, translate

and refresh the Home page. It will work.

**Solution**
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1936

Be sure that there is no php warning in your code (website).

Answer (score 11):

My solution, go to file app/Mage.php
on line 808, replace

```
$file = empty($file) ? 'system.log' : basename($file);
```

to

```
$file = empty($file) ? 'system.log' : $file;
```

and comment the following line

```
/*
if (!self::helper('log')->isLogFileExtensionValid($file)) {     
                return;     
}*/
```

Comment: This is a workaround. The clean way would be like described in this article: https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/supee-10415-causing-every-page-to-404

Comment: I got this when I upgraded to 1.9.3.10 and got 404s everywhere. This also helped me when I upgraded to 1.9.3.10 - thank you!