# Product page 404 error only sometimes

Tags: magento-1.9, php, error, 404, 404-page

I have a weird problem I can say. I'm using Magento 1.9.3.6, and **SOMETIMES, NOT ALWAYS**,  when I want to access the product page, of any product, it gives me an 404 page not found error and if I refreshed the page, goes to the product page without any 404 error. I don't know why is that. This happens only one time/2-3 days for me, but I guess it happens more often, because I have many visits on my website.
What could be the problem?Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if your [issue](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1936) is related to the latest "Known issues" for magento installations. They mention it for the version above yours, but it does not mean that the issues originated in that version specifically.
There is also a solution with cache disabling mentioned in [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204882/getting-404-page-not-found-after-upgrading-to-1-9-3-7?rq=1) ticket. That may help.
Good luck!

Comment: So I checked this out and looks like my problem is that known issue. The weird thing is that if you use third part extensions on your Magento website it is almost impossible to resolve this problem because almost every third part module came with some warnings/notices. Thanks for your help!