# Random 404 on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, http-error-404

I am experiencing random 404 on my product pages. I cant reproduce it, it happens and on reload it works. I found [Product page 404 error only sometimes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206914/product-page-404-error-only-sometimes), but I dont understand what the solution should be.

Any ideas?

**Magento 1.9.3.6**

Comment: Any update on this @Arnie? I'm having the same issue on Magento 1.9.4.4, hosted at nexcess, redis enabled, multi store(language). The whole catalog have 11 virtual products, and there's no peak access when the problem occurs. What our stores have in common?

Answer (score 0):

- check if overrides default Magento product page rendering controller
- check if there are an observer on this
- if there are a module which changes the default behavior, redirect by
  geoip etc

if nothing above, check in which cases could be 404 and add the logger to this place to determinate the issue, but I believe it's related to some module or customization.