# Magento 1.9 403 Forbidden error after trying to update

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, maintenance

I tried to update **Magento 1.9.3.3** to newer **1.9 versions** and deleted `magento_all_latest.txt` in **pkginfo** folder, also deleted **maintenance.flag** then I have this error throughout the website (`frontend`, `admin`, `downloader`):

**403 Forbidden** 
You do not have permission to access this document.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: go through this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204882/getting-404-page-not-found-after-upgrading-to-1-9-3-7

Comment: I don't have the file app/mage.php in my install it's a 1.9 Magento install